# .Net Compact Network Printing with Windows CE

Tags: .net, printing, compact-framework, windows-ce

I've found that there is no printing interface built into .Net compact, so my question is how can I print? My overall goal is just to send some basic stuff to a wireless label printer that I will connect too via a printer share on our server.

Consider the question limited to sending a 'Hello World' print job. Its a label printer so i will have to deal with sending it the PLC codes and stuff later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configuring and creating proper PCL for printers is a *lot* of work.  Consider a third-party printing solution like [PrinterCE](http://www.fieldsoftware.com/PrinterCE.htm) or [PrintBoy](http://www.bachmannsoftware.com/pbce.htm).  I've used both for a variety of printers and both work well.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to go the route of sending the data right to the device rather than through the windows printing. (Which makes a lot more sense in this situation)

The label printer comes with a software utility for creating labels and happens to save the labels in the PCL format, so I think I can use that program to make templates and insert the data where necessary.